# Redux toolkit and global API function cross-dependancy

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am facing an issue trying to dispatch a reducer in my API function, I want my function to be able to handle 401s to automatically call logout function.

I have tried importing `{ store }` and using `store.dispatch()` however there is an issue, I have some asyncThunks in my store slices and they require this global function, so whenever I try to access store in my global API function. I get an issue claiming I can't access the slice before initialization

The store slice requires the global API function to initialize, the global API function (if I add the logout on 401) requires store slices to initialize

```
// my api function
export const makeApiCall = ({method, payload, config}) => {
// something
return response: Promise<any>
}
```

```
// my slice

...storeReducers,
logout: (state) =>  {
// do some logging out
}

// issue is because I have some other async thunks that go something like

import {makeApiCall} from "path"

export const loginFunction = (payload) => {
// uses makeApiCall
}
```

How could I go about solving this issue? I can't dispatch anything because I can't import store before store is initialized, store cannot be initialized before API call function is initialized